# Retrieve large amount of records from a source and display on website

Tags: asp.net, json, xml, database, architecture

I expanding the functionality of our flight reservation website and have a requirement to handle large amount of records around 1000+ retrieve from the gateway(flight details on search).currently we handle less than 100 records and now  the app get freezes retrieving such amount of data. so can anybody suggest me a good architectural solution to how retrieve store and display the records on website.

Comment: What is the bottleneck that makes it slow? When I'm using large sets of data I'll do stored proc to get data. If its the front end I would reccomend doing paging and just getting the data as needed

Comment: Thank you Ryan for helping. Actually when the user search for flights, we are going to retrieve large number of flight detail records from a service (GDS). currently we retrieve less number of the records and keep in a cache object and show records on asp.net page by paging. So we may need to store records in an efficient manner (db, file, object etc,) some way and show with paging. Any good way of doing this ?